# Cannot get list of elements using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Sample XML:

```
<CONFIGURATION>
    <Files>
        <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile.txt</File>
        <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile01.txt</File>
        <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile02.txt</File>
        <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile03.txt</File>
        <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile04.txt</File>
    </Files>
    <SizeMB>3</SizeMB>
    <BackupLocation>D:\Log backups\File backups</BackupLocation>
</CONFIGURATION>
```

I've been doing some tutorials, but I am unable to get all the list of files inside the files element. It only shows the first <File> element and doesn't display the rest. This is my code:

```
var fileFolders = from file in XDocument.Load(@"D:\Hello\backupconfig1.xml").Descendants("Files")
                         select new
                         {
                             File = file.Element("File").Value
                         };

foreach (var fileFolder in fileFolders)
{
     Console.WriteLine("File = " + fileFolder.File);
}
```

How do I display all the File in the Files element, the SizeMB and BackupLocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an array of file locations, like `Aaron Anodide` recommended you to do. Use this array in a `for` or `foreach` loop:

```
string[] files = configuration.Element("Files").Elements("File").Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
for (int index=0; index<files.Length; index++)
{
    DoSomeStuffWithFileCLocation(files[i]);
}
```

or

```
forach(string file in files)
{
    DoSomeStuffWithFileCLocation(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked! Sorry for my stupid question though.. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Edited]

Use [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<string> files = 
    XDocumentLoad(@"D:\Hello\backupconfig1.xml").Descendants("Files")
        .SelectMany(files => files.Descendants("File"))
        .Select(file => file.Value)
```

SelectMany() concatenates multiple enumerations into one.

Comment: How do I output it? There's no select new. How do I loop it?

Comment: @Blackator I have clarified the above example to show how you can get a list of strings containing the files from it.

Answer (score 2):

```
string xml = @"<CONFIGURATION> 
<Files> 
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile.txt</File> 
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile01.txt</File> 
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile02.txt</File> 
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile03.txt</File> 
    <File>D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile04.txt</File> 
</Files> 
<SizeMB>3</SizeMB> 
<BackupLocation>D:\Log backups\File backups</BackupLocation> 
</CONFIGURATION>";

var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var configuration = xdoc.Element("CONFIGURATION");
string sizeMB = configuration.Element("SizeMB").Value;
string backupLocation = configuration.Element("BackupLocation").Value;
string[] files = configuration.Element("Files").Elements("File").Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(sizeMB);
Console.WriteLine(backupLocation);    
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", files));
```

OUTPUT

```
3
D:\Log backups\File backups
D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile.txt
D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile01.txt
D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile02.txt
D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile03.txt
D:\Test\TestFolder\TestFolder1\TestFile04.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works! However, I need to load an xml and put the <File> elements in a for loop because I will be doing something to each of the file locations.. It's my first time using Linq, I still have to study the codes and make a for loop out of it.

Comment: By the way, what's \r and \n inside string.Join for?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit more performant to do something like the following:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Hello\backupconfig1.xml");
var fileFolders = doc.Root.Element("Files").Elements("File");
```

`Descendants()` will return back a collection of all nodes in the document. In the example above it's not a big deal, but if you construct a suitably large document, this may slow things down. Instead, if you know you specifically just want the Files, then navigating to it directly with `Element()` will be quicker (and arguably more readable).